# Java Class File Editor

Tags: java, class, editor, bytecode

What is the most effective way I can decompile & Edit a class file? I really just want to edit one line of code in the file, however JBE (java ByteCode Editor) isn't letting me change a floating point constant.

Decompiling the class and recompiling will not work, as I have tried this, I get many dependency errors, and name errors.
How can I go about this effectively?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

What I personally like to use and fits exactly your problem:

http://dirty-joe.com/

Comment: Hello from almost-2019 :)

Comment: Unfortunately it requires Windows to run.

Comment: There is no source code, and it doesn't support annotation attributes

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it has been mentioned before or not but i used this http://classeditor.sourceforge.net/screenshot/index.html when i ran into the similar problem.

The tool is pretty decent, can help you look at the class files fields/methods etc. There is an option on the GUI which can be checked to edit the "values" of fields or soemthing which will reflect directly in class file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried downloading a LOT of class file decompilers and this is the best one that I found:

#### [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten/releases)

Answer (score -2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler

also it's defunct, you can also use builtin IntelliJ decompiler

Comment: I said: `Decompiling the class and recompiling will not work, as I have tried this, I get many dependency errors, and name errors. How can I go about this effectively?` Please read before posting

Comment: if you only want to change float point const why not use hex editor?

Comment: Because I don't want to screw up the rest of the class... and I have no clue how .class files are made, I just know java :)

Comment: @Richard If you change the value of a floating-point number in a hex editor, you should be fine as long as you don't change the length of the number.

Comment: I don't think that a float point constant in java .class is defined any way other that a 4 byte float point number representation, so just search for the number and change it, if you screw something there is always a way back, backup prior experimenting :)

Comment: @Troydm, thanks, that worked, but it gave unexpected results.. e.g. the constant was used elsewhere, so that code never got reached :) Ill keep toying with JBE and hexfiend...

Comment: I fear that "java.decompiler.free.fr" is definitely closed. I've updated the list of miroires this page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler. Try this link : http://jd.benow.ca

Comment: @EmmanuelDupuy Java decompiler is sooo good but the only problem is that you can't edit the class file using it